# R influence variables on y target

Tags: r, variables, model

One task of Machine Learning / Data Science is making predictions. But, I want to get more insights in the variables of my model.

To get more insights, I tried different methods:

- Logistic Regression (The output provides some 'insights' in the influence of the different variables, see: [Checking interpretation of GLM summary in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47891566/checking-interpretation-of-glm-summary-in-r))
- The xgb.plot.importance function applied on a Boosting Tree, see picture below (applied on the Titanic Data Set).

And I saw a great article (but unfortunately, it is not working) how to explain a boosting tree (see: https://medium.com/applied-data-science/new-r-package-the-xgboost-explainer-51dd7d1aa211).

My question: are there other methods to give yourself (or even better: the business) more insights about which variables have a influence on the target variable? And of course: is the influence positive/negative and how big is it?

[image: Example: xgb.plot.importance (titanic data set)]

Comment: For regression models, one option would be to calculate / plot marginal effects of the covariates used in the model. I don't have time right now to type up an answer utilizing an example, but check out Thomas J. Leeper's `margins` package, for example. Here is the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use lasso regression (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17251/what-is-the-lasso-in-regression-analysis), which basically selects the variables that influence the response variable mostly.

The `glmnet` package provides support for this type of regression.

Comment: Please consider expanding your answer. This will probably be considered as a link-only answer and consequently removed.